# How to install BeeBeep messenger in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04

I want to install beebeep messenger in my laptop running Ubuntu 15.04 - how can I install this? I also so many code for this but cannot install this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [BeeBeep](http://sourceforge.net/projects/beebeep/) for Linux. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

   ```
   wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/beebeep/Linux/beebeep-2.0.3-amd64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Unzip it :

   ```
   tar -zxvf beebeep-2.0.3-amd64.tar.gz
   ```
3. Add execution permission

   ```
   cd beebeep-2.0.3-amd64/
   sudo chmod +x beebeep
   ```
4. Install needed librairies :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxcb-screensaver0
   ```
5. Launch the application by double clicking on `beebeep` or by running in a terminal :

   ```
   ./beebeep
   ```

When the application is launched, right click on it in the taskbar and select **Lock to Launcher**.

---

Tested and working on my Ubuntu 15.04 setup.

Comment: i have already downloaded  beebeep-2.0.0-amd64.

Comment: Begin at step 2) then...

Comment: but its folder not zip file and this folder is in Documents folder.

Comment: This is the wrong version, it is the Windows version. Please just begin at step 1) it does not matter if you already have downloaded it.

Comment: ok i will try your code

Answer (score 0):

You can find a linux guide [here](http://beebeep.sourceforge.net/help.php).

Open a terminal and launch this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a libqt5gui5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libxcb-screensaver0
```